# How to add valid A record to tinydns for subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, subdomain

I try to make my subdomain operable on Centos 5 and Tinydns. I've added :

```
+en.mydomain.com:ip_address:3600
```

saved and did:

```
make
```

with no errors. But ping does not show this subdomain. What can I do to make my subdomain working using subdomain and how to diagnoze what is wrong now?

Accorindg to @womble i provide results of "Checking addresses of your computers" from:
http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/run-server.html

1. Reverse lookups: 12 my_ip.in-addr.arpa:  (not good?).
2. I get some netstat results
3. Tinydns-get size is 92 so it's less than 512.
4. Dnsq  on en.mydomain.com issued on my server ip returns valid answer
5. Dnsqr en.mydomain.com does not return answer (it's not good right?)
6. /var/tinydns/log/main folder is empty so i can not diagnose log file (how to enable it?)
7. Dnstrace shows:

   0:.:.:start:NS:.:.
   0:.:.:start:A:.:my_ip
   1:en.mydomain.com:.:my_ip:tx
   1:en.mydomain.com:.:my_ip:A:en.mydomain.com:my_ip
   1:en.mydomain.com:.:my_ip:NS:mydomain.com:ns.lxlabs.com
   1:en.mydomain.com:.:my_ip:NS:mydomain.com:ns1.lxlabs.com
   1:en.mydomain.com:.:my_ip:answer:en.mydomain.com 86400 A my_ip
   1:ns.lxlabs.com:.:my_ip:tx
   1:ns.lxlabs.com:.:my_ip:ALERT:query failed; timed out
   1:ns1.lxlabs.com:.:my_ip:tx
   1:ns1.lxlabs.com:.:my_ip:ALERT:query failed; timed out

Hope this help to provide answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use ping. Query the nameserver in question directly with nslook, dig, dnsq or whatever your favourite tool is.

Also, the "Checking addresses of your computers" part of http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/run-server.html tells you how to query the tinydns data directly.

Edit: Try see if tinydns is listening on the correct interface, run:

netstat -an | grep ".53 "

Which will show all the processes listening on port 53. There should be an entry for your external interface and not just loopback.

Comment: i have used dig as you suggested and didn't not receive any answer from tinydns. how to diagnose it?

Comment: See the second part of Alex's answer.

Comment: @wombe I've upadated question with results from "Checking addresses of your computers". Hope this will help diagose this problem. I have still no idea what can be wrong

Comment: Any chance you could give us real IP adresses and hostnames to work with?

Are you running tinydns on the loopback interface? If so, you'll only be able to reach tinydns from that host. Either run dnscache on an real network interface and let it talk to tinydns - or move tinydns to a real interface.

Comment: @Alex I've sent you real ip and hostname. How to check if tinydns runs on loopback?

Comment: As you noticed by doing dig directly on my subdomain it was not working because I configured DNS on my server where my domain uses DNS provided by my hosting provider. And he offered his panel to change DNS settings. Thank you for fiding it out and supporting me by email.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to talk to the authoritative DNS server itself, rather than going through a resolver:

```
dig en.mydomain.com @IP-of-TinyDNS
```

With DNS, if you think you've done it right, it's generally a matter of waiting - for all the other resolvers (for the DJBdns set of programs, that would be dnscache) to clear, or you can force it ("svc -t /service/dnscache") to clear.

Ping is not the right thing though - 'dnsip', or the older 'dig', above.

Comment: i've tried to force it and have this: error: svc: warning: unable to chdir to /service/dnscache: file does not exist, and dig does not display any DNS answer at all. How to force it to refresh or to diagnose what is wrong?

Comment: @Alister Bulman And when i do ps-aux I have only tinydns listed and not dnscache if it matters

Comment: I've updated question with new data

Answer (score 0):

You say you ran make but did you restart your server with `svc -t /service/tinydns`?

Change the /service/tinydns path to match your setup of course.

Comment: tinydns doesn't need to be restarted if its data.cdb changes.